# ERROR: 0 - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, fsockopen

i have one problem.. i use this function

```
public function check_ch($prt){

        $ip = "xx.xx.xx.xxx";
        $port = $prt;

       $fp = @fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr);
            if (!$fp)
              // return $port;
                return "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
            else
                return 1;

    }
```

and i got this error..

```
ERROR: 0 - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

But only in php .. i have some function in python but there it works . see here:

```
SERVER1_CHANNEL_DICT = {
    1:{'key':11,'name':'Canal 1','ip':'xx.xx.xx.xxx','tcp_port':13431,'udp_port':13431,'state':STATE_NONE,},
    2:{'key':12,'name':'Canal 2','ip':'xx.xx.xx.xxx','tcp_port':13461,'udp_port':13461,'state':STATE_NONE,},
    3:{'key':13,'name':'Canal 3','ip':'xx.xx.xx.xxx','tcp_port':13491,'udp_port':13491,'state':STATE_NONE,},
    4:{'key':14,'name':'Canal 4','ip':'xx.xx.xx.xxx','tcp_port':13521,'udp_port':13521,'state':STATE_NONE,},
    5:{'key':15,'name':'Canal 5','ip':'xx.xx.xx.xxx','tcp_port':13551,'udp_port':13551,'state':STATE_NONE,},
    6:{'key':16,'name':'Canal 6','ip':'xx.xx.xx.xxx','tcp_port':13581,'udp_port':13581,'state':STATE_NONE,},
}
```

check the pictures [image]

and i don't know why in php doesn't work.. help me please.. when i call the function i put the port .. $this->check_ch(13431) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical to me: the `fsockopen()` first argument `$site` is not set. I presume it should be `$ip` instead of `$site`.
By the way you should be careful as `fsockopen()` returns a ressource, when checking for it's return you should strict test.

```
public function check_ch($prt)
{
    $ip = "xx.xx.xx.xxx";

    $fp = @fsockopen($ip, $prt, $errno, $errstr);
    if ($fp === false) {
        // return $port;
        return "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
When you silence a function with a `@`, if you get a problem, the first reflex to have is to unsilence it. You should have a report that `$site` is not set if it was unsilenced ;)

Comment: I try but don't work.. here is my function now and in next picture how i call .. you have now port and ip

https://i.imgur.com/5hB3bV4.png
https://i.imgur.com/FSnU9U2.png

same error..

Comment: @AlexandruValentin There is still the same mistake : `$site` in first argument instead of `$ip` ;) Change it : `$fp = @fsockopen($ip, $prt, $errno, $errstr);`

Comment: But I have a server and this site is connected to mysql on that IP .. the site has another ip .. So .. I have a server and the players connect to this server from a client in Python with ip and this port .. or how to check if the mysql port is open? you can see the website here: www.m2kotoba.ro

Comment: You don't get what I try to say. You make a `fsockopen($site)` with the argument `$site` which is never set anywhere, it doesn't exist, it's quite the same thing than doing `fsockopen(null)`. That's why you get such an error, you try to open nothing.

Comment: Ah sorry.. but i got this error now.. ERROR: 111 - Connection refused 
i search how to solve that if you don't know.. and thank you so much :)

Comment: @AlexandruValentin Glad I could help, that's why SO is for :) Is your script running on the same server you try to fsockopen ? If yes, try "localhost" instead of its IP.

Comment: No server is different, I have host for web server and server for game, and I do not have firewall .. I do not know why it does not work .. I try to contact host company but i don't know they will help me..

Comment: @AlexandruValentin I don't know how to help more... Give a try on google.com on port 80 or https://www.google.com (edit: the complete url is transformed in link: use https) on port 443. If it doesn't work it's probably a PHP configuration problem or limitation on your server, if it works it's a problem on your second server (but it would be weird since it work with python)...

Comment: This is the problem.. fsockopen(): unable to connect to 89.39.12.206:13431 (Connection refused)
for google.com:80 it works, for my website with 80 it works... anyway

Comment: Then it looks like a firewall issue or something like that and it's weird it's working fine on same port with python and not here...

Comment: Oh my god ... I solved it ... I just had to add udp: // before ip .. :D good job :))

Comment: Ow effectively, standard protocol is TCP ;) if your server is waiting for udp you have to specify it. I'm glad you finally found the problem.